# How do I change the title of the legend in this ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I've tried a few methods to change the legend title, but it ends up creating a new legend with that title just below the current legend.

Here is the code:

```
C1 <- rnorm(200,14,4)
C2 <- rnorm(20,13,2)
C1.date <- sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 200)
C2.date <- sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 20)

dataset <- data.frame(c(C1,C2),c(C1.date,C2.date),c(rep("C1",200),rep("C2",20)))

names(dataset) <- c("A","B","C")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x = B, y = A))+
 enter code here`xlab("B")+
 ylab("A")+
 geom_point(aes(color = factor(C)))+
 scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y")+
 stat_smooth(aes(color = factor(C),fill = factor(C)),method="loess")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `labs` you have the change both the title for `fill` and the `color` legend. If you change only one they no longer get merged.

```r
C1 <- rnorm(200,14,4)
C2 <- rnorm(20,13,2)
C1.date <- sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 200)
C2.date <- sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 20)

dataset <- data.frame(c(C1,C2),c(C1.date,C2.date),c(rep("C1",200),rep("C2",20)))

names(dataset) <- c("A","B","C")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x = B, y = A))+
  xlab("B")+
  ylab("A")+
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(C)))+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y")+
  stat_smooth(aes(color = factor(C),fill = factor(C)),method="loess") +
  labs(color = "Legend", fill = "Legend")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be using `guides()` which is similar to the fast solution of **@stefan**:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x = B, y = A))+
  xlab("B")+
  ylab("A")+
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(C)))+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y")+
  stat_smooth(aes(color = factor(C),fill = factor(C)),method="loess")+
  guides(color=guide_legend(title='MY NEW TITLE'),
         fill=guide_legend(title='MY NEW TITLE'))
```

Output:

[image]